# Since the LXX says Wisdom was created at Proverbs 8:22 but begotten at 8:25, does this disprove "begotten not made?"

Tags: psalms, septuagint, proverbs

At **Proverbs 8:22** in the **LXX** the speaker is created with the Greek κτίζω but in verse **25** he is begotten with γεννά με.  This speaks of the same event.   According to advanced Hebrew lexicons like BDB and Halot qanah also means "*created*" at Proverbs 8:22. [2]  At verse 25, the common rendering "brought forth" is from a  Hebrew verb that Halot says means "to be brought forth (through labor pains)."

Comment: (-1) I would expect a "Biblical" proof to be founded on how the passage reads in the original language. Using the LXX does not constitute a Biblical truth, unless you are citing passages also found in the NT. Otherwise, at best, you show what a translator(s) thought.

Comment: @RevelationLad  I quote the LXX to show how the Greek κτίτζω (create) is used as a synonym for γίνομαι (be born).    It's a built in lexicon.

Comment: Mountains are created. Being 'born' is a metaphor when related to mountains. Mountains do not beget mountains.

Comment: Once again, you seem to be confusing hermeneutics with [linguistics](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com). This question basically boils down to asking when the Greeks started differentiating between the two forms of one and the same polysemantic word. (Similarly for the Latin *[pro]creation*).

Comment: I removed my comment so that you can calm down. By the way, I didn't mark this as off-topic.

Comment: Btw, the close reason "opinion-based" is not saying that your question has opinions in it, but that the only possible answers will be opinion-based. An obvious example would be something like "What's the best book of the Bible?" where answers will wholly depend on peoples' personal values/opinions.

Comment: I've re-opened the question. Am I understanding correctly that you're asking if there is any substantial semantic difference between these two words given that they are used in these two places in similar ways?

Answer (score 3):

***"qanah"* in the Beginning**

> <sup>22</sup> “The LORD possessed <sup>[b]</sup> me at the beginning of his work,<sup>[c]</sup> the first of his acts of old. <sup>23</sup> Ages ago I was set up, at the first, before the beginning of the earth. <sup>24</sup> When there were no depths I was brought forth, when there were no springs abounding with water. <sup>25</sup> Before the mountains had been shaped, before the hills, I was brought forth (Proverbs 8 ESV)
>
> [b] Proverbs 8:22 Or *fathered*; Septuagint *created*
>   [c] Proverbs 8:22 Hebrew *way*
>
> 8:22 יהוה **קנני** ראשית דרכו קדם מפעליו מאז
>   8:23 מעולם נסכתי מראש מקדמי-ארץ
>   8:24 באין-תהמות **חוללתי** באין מעינות נכבדי-מים
>   8:25 בטרם הרים הטבעו לפני גבעות **חוללתי**

First, the more common meaning of קנני *[qanah](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H7069&t=KJV)* is possessed, as in the ESV, and [others](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Proverbs%208:22). However, Michael V. Fox notes it should be considered "create" in this passage since the following verse speaks clearly of creation:

> Since ancient times, interpreters have disputed whether the verb "kanah" means "created" or "acquired." The latter allows for the possibility that wisdom existed from eternity and was coeval with God. Some Christian groups preferred this, since they identified wisdom with the Logos, which in turn identified with Christ. It is, however, clear from v. 23 that wisdom is a created being. In fact, "kanah" refers to acquisition by any means, including creation, as here.<sup>`1`</sup>

Therefore, the proper meaning must be considered by examining both verses.

> <sup>22</sup> The Lord created me as the beginning of his ways, for the sake of his works. <sup>23</sup> Before the present age he founded me in the beginning. ([NETS](http://ccat.sas.upenn.edu/nets/edition/25-proverbs-nets.pdf))
>   <sup>22</sup> κύριος ἔκτισέν με ἀρχὴν ὁδῶν αὐτοῦ εἰς ἔργα αὐτοῦ <sup>23</sup> πρὸ τοῦ αἰῶνος ἐθεμελίωσέν με ἐν ἀρχῇ

The Greek, κτίζω is "to create," but the next verse introduces a different uncertainty as ἐθεμελίωσέν με ἐν ἀρχῇ, "founded me in the beginning," conflates two different descriptions of time in the Hebrew text (ראשית in 8:22 and מראש in 8:23) with one word, [ἀρχῇ](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G746&t=KJV). In other words, the certainty of *qanah* Fox asserts is present in the Hebrew, is not present in the Greek. Does the Greek mean wisdom was created and founded in the beginning or are there two separate beginnings or is one use of ἀρχῇ a beginning and the other a source? Regardless, ἔκτισέν με ἀρχὴν... ἐθεμελίωσέν με ἐν ἀρχῇ cannot be taken without question to mean "created in the beginning."

**I was *"chuwl"***
The next part of the question deals with the meaning of חוללתי *[chuwl](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H2342&t=KJV)* which is found 62 times and rarely, if ever used to mean "begotten." Arguably, rendered using [γεννάω](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G1080&t=KJV) is a mistranslation as it does not appear חוללתי is elsewhere translated as γεννάω. For example, the issue may be seen in Deuteronomy 32:18:

> You were unmindful of the Rock that bore you, and you forgot the God who gave you birth.
>   צור **ילדך** תשי ותשכח אל **מחללך**
>
> You abandoned God who **bore** you, and you forgot God who **nurtures** you.
>   θεὸν τὸν **γεννήσαντά** σε ἐγκατέλιπες καὶ ἐπελάθου θεοῦ τοῦ τρέφοντός σε

Here, ילדך is rendered with γεννάω as is common throughout the LXX, while מחללך is rendered with τρέφω. There is another question about translating the Hebrew because the identical word in the previous verse was not translated with γεννάω. Either the translator understood the incongruity of offering a passage which implies two births or they sought to give emphasis to a single event for some other reason.

This may be the case as γεννάω is infrequent in Proverbs being used only three other times:

> A righteous son is born to life, but the pursuit of the impious leads to death. (11:19)
>
> You should have a friend for every season, but let brothers be supportive in distress, for on this account they are born. (17:17)
>
> Listen my son, to your father who begat you, and do not despise her when your mother gets old. (23:22)

While the common meaning of γεννάω is to "begat" children, there is a sense which is perhaps more applicable when considering Wisdom literature:

> in a Jewish sense, of one who brings others over to his way of life: ὑμᾶς ἐγέννησα I am the author of your Christian life, 1 Corinthians 4:15; Philemon 1:10 (Sanhedr. fol. 19, 2 "If one teaches the son of his neighbor the law, the Scripture reckons this the same as though he had begotten him"; [cf. Philo, leg. ad Gaium § 8]).<sup>`2`</sup>

It seems this is the sense intended in 11:19. That is, not that a son has has been "born" in the physical sense; rather through wisdom they are righteous and "born" to a different life than the impious pursue.

This focus is particularly relevant in attempting to establish with certainty the meaning of κτίζω which also means to transform:

> A clean heart create in me O God, and an upright spirit renew within me. (Psalm 50:12 [51:10])
>   καρδίαν καθαρὰν κτίσον ἐν ἐμοί ὁ θεός καὶ πνεῦμα εὐθὲς ἐγκαίνισον ἐν τοῗς ἐγκάτοις μου

It certainly fits the genre and other translation decisions made but, regardless, the LXX cannot be stated as proving the "begetting" of wisdom "in the beginning."

**Psalm 90[89]**

> Before the mountains were brought forth, or ever you had formed the earth and the world, from everlasting to everlasting you are God. (ESV)
>   בטרם הרים ילדו ותחולל ארץ ותבל ומעולם עד-עולם אתה אל
>
> Before the mountains were brought forth and the earth and the world were formed, and from everlasting to everlasting you are.
>   πρὸ τοῦ ὄρη γενηθῆναι καὶ πλασθῆναι τὴν γῆν καὶ τὴν οἰκουμένην καὶ ἀπὸ τοῦ αἰῶνος ἕως τοῦ αἰῶνος σὺ εἶ

Here חוללתי *chuwl* is rendered with [γίνομαι](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G1096&t=KJV), not with γεννάω as in Proverbs. This is perhaps the word which ought to have been used in Proverbs 8:25, but as the two passages stand, other than a common theme, there is no textual support for a "proof" in Proverbs.

**Conclusion**
The Greek text for the entire passage cannot be used as a proof regarding wisdom being "created" and/or its state of being "begotten."

---

<sub>1. Michael V. Fox, *The Jewish Study Bible*, Edited by Adele Berlin and Marc Zvi Brettler, Oxford University Press, 2004, p. 1461

2. [Thayers](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G1080&t=KJV)</sub>